# Indexing with Solr-spark and Alluxio : cannot acces files in Alluxio

Tags: java, apache-spark, solr, solrj, alluxio

I am indexing documents to solr using java. My code works perfectly when I index files that are in my computer.
But when I try to index files that are located in alluxio I have an exception "No fileSystem for scheme: alluxio". I have added alluxio dependencies in my pom.

Here is the code:

```html
public class SparkTestMain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     


            new SparkRead().loadDocuments(
                    "alluxio://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:19998/**/"       );

 }

}
```

In SparkRead I do the indexing from the filepath : JavaRDD documents = sc.textFile(pathToFile) here, pathToFile = "alluxio://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:19998/**/"

Here is the error:

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2579)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2586)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:256)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [doc](https://www.alluxio.org/docs/1.8/en/operation/Troubleshooting.html#q-why-do-i-see-exceptions-like-no-filesystem-for-scheme-alluxio) from Alluxio project website explaining why you might see "No fileSystem for scheme: alluxio".

> A: This error message is seen when your applications (e.g., MapReduce,
>   Spark) try to access Alluxio as an HDFS-compatible file system, but
>   the alluxio:// scheme is not recognized by the application. Please
>   make sure your HDFS configuration file core-site.xml (in your default
>   hadoop installation or spark/conf/ if you customize this file for
>   Spark) has the following property:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>   <property>
>     <name>fs.alluxio.impl</name>
>     <value>alluxio.hadoop.FileSystem</value>
>   </property>
> </configuration>
> ```

In your posted error messages, I did see "No FileSystem for scheme: http" rather than "No fileSystem for scheme: alluxio". Is "http" a typo?